# "Is you is or is you ain't my baby?"

Tags: grammaticality, questions, negation, verb-agreement

Is this phrase grammatically correct?

> Is you is or is you ain't my baby?

It's from a Tom and Jerry cartoon: http://vimeo.com/40283242 (at 1:30, 2:00 and 3:00).

Comment: 1:30, 2:00 and 3:00. All the lyrics are handily subtitled, and are all similar AAVE-type dialect. It sounds like Louis Armstrong.

Comment: It's well discussed on this page http://stancarey.wordpress.com/2012/06/19/is-you-is-or-is-you-aint-bad-grammar/

Answer (score 2):

It's a [1944 song](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is_You_Is_or_Is_You_Ain%27t_My_Baby) sung by [blues singers](http://www.metrolyrics.com/is-you-is-or-is-you-aint-my-baby-lyrics-bb-king.html), [jazz vocalists](http://www.sing365.com/music/lyric.nsf/Is-You-is-or-is-You-Ain%27t-My-Baby-lyrics-Diana-Krall/2FC84A172534749A482569590002998F), & [pop singers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vic_Damone) from the mid-20th century. Sounds more like Fats Waller than Louis Armstrong.

The Wikipedia article says "The phrase 'Is you is or is you ain't' is dialect, apparently first recorded in a 1921 story by Octavus Roy Cohen, a Jewish writer from South Carolina who wrote humorous black dialect fiction."

It's not grammatical standard English, but it's not intended to be. It's a song lyric.

The [link to the blog post about grammaticality](http://stancarey.wordpress.com/2012/06/19/is-you-is-or-is-you-aint-bad-grammar/) in Stan's comment is a really good one, so I'm copying it for this answer.